# Node.js Puppeteer & Cheerio Div Table Scraping

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I have been working on a node.js scraper using puppeteer and cheerio but am having an issue pulling some div table information. I need to pull the the fruit and vegetable tables but not the meat table and all 3 are not always present.

```html
<div class="specs__title">
 <h4>Fruit</h4>
</div>
<div class="specs__table">
 <div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Apples</div>
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell">4lbs</div>
 </div>
 <div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Grapes</div>
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell">3lbs</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="specs__title">
 <h4>Vegetables</h4>
</div>
<div class="specs__table">
 <div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Carrots</div>
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell">7lbs</div>
 </div>
 <div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Corn</div>
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell">5lbs</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="specs__title">
 <h4>Meat</h4>
</div>
<div class="specs__table">
 <div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Turkey</div>
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell">2lbs</div>
 </div>
 <div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Beef</div>
  <div class="col-6 specs__cell">1lb</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have any code to share to see where you may have gone wrong?

Comment: The problem is I am not sure where to begin. I need something that will pull the html of the div.specs__table if the div.specs__title before it has Vegetables or Fruit in the h4 tag. I am not sure how to do that with cheerio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it but this is how I got it working.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 if($('#specsContainer > div.specs__title > h4', html).eq(i).text() == "Fruits"){
  console.log($('#specsContainer > div.specs__table', html).eq(i).html());
 };
 if($('#specsContainer > div.specs__title > h4', html).eq(i).text() == "Vegetables"){
  console.log($('#specsContainer > div.specs__table', html).eq(i).html());
 };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this: (not tested)

```
$('h4:contains("Fruits"),h4:contains("Vegetables")').map((i, h4) => {
  return $(h4).parent().find('+ .specs__table').html()
}).get()
```